# iOS battery level not changing when in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello so i have a function in my app which will notificate user when his battery is under 20% for example

in my AppDelegate.m i have this (Observer)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStatut) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
}
```

And this void which nslog's the updated battery level

```
-(void)batteryStatut{
    float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];
    batteryLevel *= 100;
    NSLog(@"Battery lvl changed: %f",batteryLevel);
}
```

Edit:

Done it adding UIBackgroundModes in plist with App uses your location and it works but its not the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to work in background, you have to declare that you app supports background tasks.
To do that you have to register a value in your .plist for `UIBackgroundModes`.

Unfortunately, you have to have a good reason to use background task.
Like listening music, location, voip etc...
Therefore I guess you won't be able to use background task for your use case without dirty things (like using location to not kill your app)

For more detail check [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)